# how to drop foreign key constraint

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to delete a Foreign Key Constraint from a table, but not sure which table is that. I just have this information. Please check the screenshot
[image]

I want to drop a table but its not allowing me to drop due to some FK constraints. Table I want to delete is 'ZIP_Codes'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this query will give the Foreign key name and the referencing table name

```
SELECT CAST(F.NAME AS VARCHAR(255)) AS FOREIGN_KEY_NAME
, CAST(P.NAME AS VARCHAR(255)) AS PARENT_TABLE
FROM SYSOBJECTS F
INNER JOIN SYSREFERENCES R ON F.ID = R.CONSTID
INNER JOIN SYSOBJECTS P ON R.RKEYID = P.ID
INNER JOIN SYSCOLUMNS RC ON R.RKEYID = RC.ID AND R.RKEY1 = RC.COLID
WHERE F.TYPE = 'F'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @parent_object_id int;
DECLARE @TableName varchar(255);
SET @parent_object_id = 1234103437;

SELECT  @TableName = OBJECT_NAME(object_id)
FROM sys.objects
Where object_id = @parent_object_id;

ALTER TABLE [TableName] DROP CONSTRAINT [ForeignKeyName]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server Management Studio,

right click on your table and click `View Dependencies` to know all the opjects dependent on your table.. you can also see objects on which your table depends by selecting corresponding option button..

Its better to know what objects you are dropping and what significance they have, before you do it.

Answer (score 0):

To find all tables that have foreign keys that point to your Zip_Codes table:

```
select object_schema_name([parent_object_id]), object_name([parent_object_id]), [name]
from sys.foreign_keys
where referenced_object_id = object_id('ZIP_Codes')
```